# classicthesis - customize parts from part x to chapter x

Tags: classicthesis, parts

I would like to change naming style used for Parts in classicthesis. I know I can eliminate the use of parts altogether but I have a summary text before each chapter so I would like to keep it. Just change it to say Chapter X instead of Part X.  I would appreciate your help. Like so:

[image]

I used suggestion by JohannesB and modified the part description in the CT.sty below and it does what I want except the numbering is off. It is picking the number of the chapter prior but I want it to pick the number ahead. So in the image above the right chapter number should be II but my hack produces chapter I. How can i nudge it to say chatter II instead 
ty

```
\documentclass[
        twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
        footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
        dottedtoc, 
        BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, 
        ngerman,american, 
        ]{scrreprt}


\input{classicthesis-config}
    \titleformat{\part}[display]
        {\normalfont\centering\large}%
        {\thispagestyle{empty}\chaptername~\MakeTextUppercase{\thechapter}}{1em}%
        {\color{Maroon}\spacedallcaps}
\begin{document}
\part{Wombats are cute}
\chapter{Capybaras are huge}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

Got it working by replacing `\thechapter` with `\thepart` in above.
Strange thing is I had tried that very hack before posting the question in the first place.

Comment: Please provide an MWE. You are likely to get a quicker (and better) response.

Comment: did you try `\let\partname\chaptername`

Comment: A part is a part and a chapter is a chapter. I don't see the point in making part behave like a chapter, rather say chapter to look like a part.

Comment: @Johannes_B, How can I make the chapter behave like a part?

Comment: @touhami `\let\partname\chaptername` leads me to a `\@secondoftwRunaway argu`

Comment: can you please add a minimal example of  code?

Comment: Can you add your full solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

If I got it right you plan to insert some text between the chapter number and the chapter title. Imho this is a bad idea and only confusing for the reader.

But if you insist to do it, you shouldn't misuse `\part` (which you will perhaps need later) but redefine some suitable `\chapter` command.

**Without** your classicthesis-config which I don't have something like the following would work. With classicthesis (which loads titlesec) you can check the examples of chapters with rules between chapter number and chapter title in the titlesec documentation.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\orichapterheadmidvskip\chapterheadmidvskip

\newcommand\insertchaptermidtext[1]
 {\renewcommand\chapterheadmidvskip
   {\begingroup\par \chapterheadendvskip
    \normalfont\normalsize #1\par
    \chapterheadstartvskip\endgroup
    \global\let\chapterheadmidvskip\orichapterheadmidvskip}}

 \begin{document}

\insertchaptermidtext{\lipsum[1]}
\chapter{Capybaras are huge}

\chapter{Wombats}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the definiton of parts from the package file to the main file and replace the instances of `part` with `chapter`.

[image: godeyClassicthesis]

```
\documentclass[
        twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
        footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
        dottedtoc, 
        BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, 
        ngerman,american, 
        ]{scrreprt} 


\input{classicthesis-config}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib} 



    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\normalfont\centering\large}%
        {\thispagestyle{empty}\chaptername~\MakeTextUppercase{\thechapter}}{1em}%
        {\color{Maroon}\spacedallcaps}
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}% If you really want roman numbering

\begin{document}
\part{Wombats are cute}
\chapter{Capybaras are huge}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Appricaite you example but that modifies the chapter style which is not what i want. It gave me an idea that is working somehow but the numbering is off. See edits to question if you can help.

Comment: @Godey Minimal working example needed.

Comment: please see my edits to question

Answer (score 0):

This is the full solution

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
    footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
    dottedtoc, 
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, 
    ngerman,american, 
    ]{scrreprt}


\input{classicthesis-config}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\normalfont\centering\large}%
    {\thispagestyle{empty}\chaptername~\MakeTextUppercase{\thepart}}{1em}%
    {\color{Maroon}\spacedallcaps}
\begin{document} 
\part{Wombats are cute}
\chapter{Capybaras are huge}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is the most confusing thing i have ever seen. The command part, that is outputting a part is outputting a chapter, Now my question: What is `\chapter` outputting? A subchapter? A section?